# How to split last word before a certain char in python string and replace that same line in a txt file?

Tags: python

I am currently trying to repeatedly replace a word in a line but there are two current issues with my code. I can successfully locate the lines I want to replace, but with my current code i fail to 1. store the specific value in the strings that i want and then replace the word on that same line.

The text I want to replace appears to two times and looks like this in the textfile:

```
One_Number_ = "0"
if [ One_Number_ == "0" ]
```

I wish to change "One" here to something else each time I run the program. What I've tried to do is the following:

```
with open(os.path.join('file.txt'), 'r') as file:
lines = file.readlines()


with open(os.path.join('file.txt'), 'w') as file:
    for line in lines:
        if (line.__contains__('_Number_')):

            replaceline = line.rsplit('_', 1)[0]
            line.replace (replaceline, "NewWord")
        file.write(line)
```

The if-statement runs but the line does not replace "One".

The strings also do not get separated correctly meaning that `replaceline`does not contain just the "One".

How can I adjust my code so it successfully locates the two lines in the textfile that needs to replaced with the new string ("NewWord", as I have just used as an example just now)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do the [`.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) like:

```
line = line.replace (replaceline, "NewWord")
```

The `replace` method returns a new string is does not modify the existing string.

Comment: Alright! 1/2 things works now. Now its just the part where the string does not store "One" correctly.

Comment: I am not sure I understand this comment.  You have more than one question here, and you expect them all to be answered?

Comment: well 2 different ones but they kinda belong together. also they r small things so i included both

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez, You are trying to find `One`?  Why are you splitting on the `_`?

Comment: Because i want to use it repeatadly, so the new value ("NewValue") will always change each time

Comment: I see no "NewValue".  The way you expect to find the thing to replace is quite unclear.

Comment: "NewWord" sorry